# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. Error when trying to update database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

When I update my database i get this error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

here are my context class and startup class

`DataBaseContext.cs`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Models;


namespace MovieExampleApp.Persistention
{
  public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
  {
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> context) : base(context)
    {
        //Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    public DatabaseContext()
    {
    }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
  }
}
```

```
Startup.cs
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using System.Linq;
using MovieExampleApp.Persistention;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;


namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));



            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
            });

        }

        private static NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter GetJsonPatchInputFormatter()
        {
            var builder = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging()
                .AddMvc()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            return builder
                .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>()
                .Value
                .InputFormatters
                .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter>()
                .First();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this ? DefaultConnection

Comment: It is my connectionstring.

Comment: Why do you need 3 constructors in your DbContext? The one with generic DbContextOptions is enough. Try to remove other two

Comment: When i remove  the other 2 it gives me an error.

Comment: What error? What do the connection strings look like? The error complains about missing information in the connection strings

Comment: "ConnectionString": "Data Source=IDKTNZDEV01\\SQLSERVER2017,1533;Initial Catalog=v;User ID=*;Password=*-;Max Pool Size=150"

Comment: It needs to be like this:
`"ConnectionStrings": {
 "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=IDKTNZDEV01\\SQLSERVER2017,1533;Initial Catalog=v;User ID=*;Password=*-;Max Pool Size=150"
`

Comment: I have always declared connection strings like this "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=IDKTNZDEV01\\SQLSERVER2017,1533;Database=Use;D=*;Password=*-;;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }

Comment: @Dave Changed it but didn't work still getting the same error.

Comment: @level_zebra Doesn't work same error.

Comment: Change `public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)` to `public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)`

Comment: @Dave that doesn't work

Comment: check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/index?tabs=dotnet-core-cli,

Comment: I think this kind of a bug. Not working for me too, and I did this dozens of times with EF and never had this kind of stress. Three days in a row stucked with this error. Going crazy.